# How do I show a "2xN" grid from desktop "1x2*N" on mobile?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to make layout like this

On PC:

`List 1 |List2
L1.Item1|L2.Item1
L1.Item2|L2.Item2
L1.ItemN|L2.ItemN`.

Show on mobile like this:

`List 1 
L1.Item1
L1.Item2
L1.ItemN
List2
L2.Item1
L2.Item2
L2.ItemN`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px repeat(auto-fit, auto);
  background-color: #1aaa00;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid > * {
  outline: 1px dashed #666;
}

.head {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="head">Header</div>
    <div>List 1</div>
    <div>List 2</div>
    <div>Position 1. List 1 <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa aliquam ipsa alias molestias accusamus enim veritatis! Pariatur fugiat maiores fuga sed nisi itaque quisquam, recusandae, accusamus cumque. Facilis, ipsum, vitae?</div>
    <div>Position 1. List 2</div>
    <div>Position 2. List 1</div>
    <div>Position 2. List 2 <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, dolorum!</div>
    <div>Position 3. List 1</div>
    <div>Position 3. List 2</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Every item must be opposite the same item at neighbouring list. The number of rows is not fixed but same at both lists. Height of rows can be different also. It depends on content.

How can I show on mobile List 1 first and List 2 under it?

I tried grid-auto-flow: column, and reorder DIVs in HTML, but I need to specify grid-template-rows to make it work. And I don't know how much rows will it be so don't know how much 1fr set there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the order of only the second elements of the column using `nth-child()` then simply make your layout one column on mobile:

```css
/*html,
body {
  height: 100%;
} no more needed with 100vh*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #1aaa00;
  min-height: 100vh; /*better use min-height*/
  text-align: center;
}

.grid>* {
  outline: 1px dashed #666;
}

.head {
  grid-column: 1 / -1; /*use -1 to avoid creating a extra column on mobile*/
  min-height: 50px;
}

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr; /*one column*/
  }
  .grid> :nth-child(2n+1) {
    order: 2; /*all the list2 at the bottom*/
  }
  .grid>div.head {
    order: -1; /*the head should stay on the top*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="head">Header</div>
  <div>List 1</div>
  <div>List 2</div>
  <div>Position 1. List 1 <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa aliquam ipsa alias molestias accusamus enim veritatis! Pariatur fugiat maiores fuga sed nisi itaque quisquam, recusandae, accusamus cumque. Facilis, ipsum, vitae?</div>
  <div>Position 1. List 2</div>
  <div>Position 2. List 1</div>
  <div>Position 2. List 2 <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, dolorum!</div>
  <div>Position 3. List 1</div>
  <div>Position 3. List 2</div>
</div>
```

In case you want to have the good order in your HTML code you can try this:

```css
/*html,
body {
  height: 100%;
} no more needed with 100vh*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #1aaa00;
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /*to fill all the space*/
  min-height: 100vh; /*better use min-height*/
  text-align: center;
}

.grid>* {
  outline: 1px dashed #666;
  grid-column:1; /*list one column 1*/
}


.l2,
.l2 ~ * {
  grid-column:2; /*list two column 2*/
}


.head {
  grid-column: 1 / -1; /*use -1 to avoid creating a extra column on mobile*/
  min-height: 50px;
}

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr; /*one column*/
  }
  .l2,
  .l2 ~ * {
    grid-column:1; /*list two column 1*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="head">Header</div>
  <div>List 1</div>
  <div>Position 1. List 1 <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa aliquam ipsa alias molestias accusamus enim veritatis! Pariatur fugiat maiores fuga sed nisi itaque quisquam, recusandae, accusamus cumque. Facilis, ipsum, vitae?</div>
  <div>Position 1. List 1</div>
  <div>Position 3. List 1</div>
  <div class="l2">List 2</div>
  <div>Position 1. List 2</div>
  <div>Position 2. List 2 <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, dolorum!</div>
  <div>Position 3. List 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But it would be quite easy if works something like that:

`grid-auto-flow: column;
grid-template-columns: 1fr;`

Comment: And set html like this:
`<div class="grid">
   <div>List 1</div>
   <div>Position 1. List 1</div>
   <div>Position 2. List 1</div>
   <div>Position 3. List 1</div>


   <div>List 2</div>
   <div>Position 1. List 2</div>
   <div>Position 2. List 2</div>
   <div>Position 3. List 2</div>
</div>`

Comment: And let grid to set them like in `grid-auto-flow: row` mode but from top to bottom here splitting by 2 columns. Is there some opportunities like this?

Comment: @user3055346 so basically you would like to keep the html structured with "all list1"  then "all list2" ?

Comment: Yes. I can change html structure and group that divs to "all list1" and then "all list2"

Comment: Thank you. I meant with `grid-auto-flow: row; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr` grid automaticaly puts cells like this http://s1.micp.ru/USGS1.png
Is there a way to make put cells just write `grid-auto-flow: column; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr` and set like that http://s3.micp.ru/1AfYj.png

Comment: @user3055346 no I don't think so, grid don't have the ability to do this ... but you can probably look at column (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) it should be perfect for your use case